# How do I replace the query parameters, and nothing else?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am making a simple pagination component, it sets the "page" query param in the url. However, my link redirects me to the root of my application whenever I click it, instead of just changing the query. Any ideas?

```
export default class ListNavigation extends React.Component {
  render () {
    let props = this.props;
    let page = props.page;

    return (
      <div class="list-navigation layout_flexbox">
        <Link to={{query: {page: page + 1}}}>Next</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I need the "Next" link to only add 1 to the "page" query param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try adding pathname as well?

```
const {location: {pathname}, page} = this.props;

return (
  <div class="list-navigation layout_flexbox">
    <Link to={{pathname, query: {page: page + 1}}}>Next</Link>
  </div>
)
```

Comment: The syntax at the top of your code confuses me, can you explain what it does?

Comment: i used es6 destructuring. it gets location out of this.props & then retrieves pathname from location. [this blog](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) is a good place to read more about it.